# Powershell | Array - Select from - to

Tags: arrays, powershell

is there a way to select some objects of an array "from-to"?

```
$data = @('A1','A2','A3','A4','B1','B2','B3','B4')
$data |Select-Object A3 - B2
```

in my example i want to select only A3-B2 but i dont want to write them down like this

```
 $data |Select-Object A3, A4, B1, B2
```

Comment: You mean `$data[2..5]`?

Comment: yes 2...5 is it possible to get the like this 2-5

Answer (score 0):

Since you are operating on array, you can directly slice the array from `2` to `5`. ie,

```
$data[2..5]
```

If you still want to use `Select-Object`, you can use it with `-Index` parameter. This will *[Selects objects from an array based on their index values.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters)*

```
$data | Select-Object -Index @(2..5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve part of the array using a range operator for the index in your case it will be from the 3rd item to the 6th

`$data [2..5]`

or you can do this with negative numbers counts

`$data [-3..-6]`
you can read more on the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2)